# Update the list view after adding a new item in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `ListView` and it binds data from the database. This is the code to bind date from database. After adding a new item, the list view is not updated. But in the database, the table gets updated. The code I used to bind the list view:

```
public void BindIncomeExpense()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U1OP1S9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PaintStores;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "sp_getAllIncomeExpense";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dataTable);

    for(int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow drow = dataTable.Rows[i];
        // Only row that have not been deleted
        if(drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
        {
            // Define the list items
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["Description"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Category"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Amount"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(drow["Date"].ToString());

            listView9.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

And to add new item

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U1OP1S9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PaintStores;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_saveIncomeExpense", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", comboBox12.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", textBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker12.Value);
    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    if(i != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully");
        this.Close();
    }

    Main frm = new Main();
    frm.BindIncomeExpense();
}
```

And I can't understand why the storedprocedure didn't return the lastly added data to the listview. In the database when I execute the sp, it returns the last data also.

Comment: The code you posted, is that part of the `Main` form, or another form? Also, if it's part of another form, does that form already contain a reference to your _existing_ `Main` window? I'm pretty sure I see the issue but I need the extra info to provide you with an answer.

Comment: @AmitJoshi: Your answer makes an assumption as to how the reference to the main form is tracked. I'm asking OP for specific feedback so I can tailor my answer to his needs. Your answer excludes the possibility of the sample code already being part of the `Main` form itself.

Comment: @Flater the BindIncomeExpense method is in Main form. And the other code is in another form. That is AddNew form. I want to update the listview in the main form after I add an item using the AddNew form

Comment: @Coderstech: Thanks for the response, will create an appropriate answer.

Comment: AmitJoshi has updated his answer faster than I could write mine. Although I would have approached it slightly differently; his example is functionally identical and will solve the problem (as both me and Amit see it).

Answer (score 2):

`Main frm = new Main();`
This might be the problem. You are creating new instance of form. This might not be the same that is being displayed on screen. Use the same instance that you used to display the form on screen.

For example, somewhere in your code you have already loaded `Main` form using

```
Main frmOriginal = new Main();
frmOriginal.Show();// or ShowDialog or Application.Run
```

Your `frmOriginal` instance should be accessible while calling binding method.
Your new code should be something like:

```
//Main frm = new Main();//Do not use this
frmOriginal.BindIncomeExpense();//Use the instance of form that is already being displayed.
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, you need to pass instance of `Main` form to `IncomeExpense` form.
Following code will be on `Main` form to create `IncomeExpense` form:

```
IncomeExpense incomeExpense = new IncomeExpense();
incomeExpense.ShowDialog(this);
```

On `IncomeExpense` form:

```
//Main frm = new Main();//Do not use this
this.Owner.BindIncomeExpense();
```

Comment: But, not only in the list view, but in the drop down also, if I add a new item, it didn't loaded. After I stop the program and restart only all are displayed.

Comment: 'button1_Click' write in another form and 'BindIncomeExpense' is in main form.

Comment: But My AddNew form starts with ` public partial class IncomeExpense : Form`  This implies the AddNew form is not created from the Main form. so How can I use that?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.
I used

```
if(System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Main"] != null)
        {
            (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Main"] as Main).BindIncomeExpense();
        }
```

to call the current instance of the Main form. Now it is working according to my requirement. Complete code in the IncomeExpense form to save the data is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-U1OP1S9\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PaintStores;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_saveIncomeExpense", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", comboBox12.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker12.Value);
        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();

        if (i != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully");
            this.Close();
        }

        if(System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Main"] != null)
        {
            (System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Main"] as Main).BindIncomeExpense();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Thank you all for your help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Please bind Again the data from database to get the new data added i.e simply called the function to bind the data after saving the data into database

Comment: I called that as Main frm = new Main();
        frm.BindIncomeExpense();

Comment: Make sure that you select the data from database and I don't see the connection string when you are getting the data from the database i.e command.connection part in the code

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure `sp_getAllIncomeExpense` returns data correctly.

Comment: Yeah. At the same time during the execution, I execute the sp. It returns all the data in the database. But in the code It didn't return the lastly added data.